# I'm currently trying to make a Powershell script that opens a certain file from a path file. But, i dont really know what to put here

Tags: powershell

So this is my current code:

> run C:\Users\admin\Desktop\poweshell testiN\tEST.txt

And what comes out is:

> The term 'run' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file
> , or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was include
> d, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:4
>
> - run <<<<  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\poweshell testiN\tEST.txt
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (run:String) [], CommandNotFound     Exception
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I dont really know what to put in my code.
I know that one idea is that "Why are you using a .bat file format", please, I don't even know what to do here. Please do tell me what command should i use, or suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no `run` command in PowerShell, you might want `Invoke-Item C:\path\to.txt` (or `ii C:\path\to.txt`)

Comment: A simple dot `.`. = `. C:\Users\admin\Desktop\poweshell testiN\tEST.txt`. `&` works too. See [source](https://ss64.com/ps/source.html)

Comment: Dot-sourcing isn't what you want in this case. Use `Invoke-Item` or the call operator `&`

Comment: Dot source does what ampersand does but keeps it in the calling session from my understanding

Comment: I did not know that run did not exist, so thanks to that too. I'll take note of these. Thanks guys for the help!

Comment: I well @MathiasR.Jessen 's code somewhat did not work just to an error, but no worries it just needed a second of googling. In his case his code was `Invoke-Item C:\path\to.txt` , just change it to `Invoke-Item "C:\path\to.txt"`.

Comment: Why are you trying to open a text file in the consolehost, from the PowerShell console host? That's not a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows Key + R and in the run box do this...

```
PowerShell d:\temp\abc.txt
```

Powershell will flash an open the file in notepad.

If you are in the PowerShell consolehost, just type the file name and hit enter and the default app will open it.

```
d:\Temp\abc.txt
```

If you are in the PowerShell ISE, then in the ISE editor pane or the ISE integrated console, just do this...

```
psEdit -filenames D:\Temp\abc.txt
```

This will open the text file in a PowerShell ISE editor pane. No external program required.

If you are saying you have PowerShell code in that file you'd what to run, which I'd ask, why, then you need to read the file and process its content not just open it, or it needs to be a PowerShell script (.ps1) that has functions you may want to user, then you load the code using the dot sourcing... So, in the console host, do this...

```
 . .d:\temp\abc.ps1
```

If your file has spaces or special characters, then it must be properly quoted.

All of the above is PowerShell day 1 basic. So, if you have not yet gotten any ramp up on PowerShell, get this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085RQNL9X) or use [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell/index.htm) or [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning%20powershell).

Lastly, if you want to use a command that does say, 'run', there are a few commands that do that.

```
Start-Process 'D:\Temp\abc.txt'
Start 'D:\Temp\abc.txt'
Invoke-Item 'D:\Temp\abc.txt'
ii 'D:\Temp\abc.txt'
& 'D:\Temp\abc.txt'
```

Read the Powershell help system for these cmdlet/alias details